# How do I integrate a Symfony controller action in a legacy PHP page?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I do have a legacy PHP application and a Symfony 4.1 application. I need to integrate both by rendering parts of a plain PHP page as the result of a predetermined controller action. That is, no resolving based on request is necessary or wanted and the response body should be inserted in the legacy page.

Put differently: I want Symfony to act on the current request, but in advance tell it to use ExampleController::exampleAction() and get the response (body). What is the cleanest way to achieve that?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you are asking but a [controller kernel listener](https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html) allows you to do some processing before controller actions are called.

Comment: I mainly need to set the controller and action, which would be possible with a kernel.request listener (possibly others, too). Adding the attribute during request creation is way simpler in this case, though.

Comment: Side note, you can drop the “action” sufix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is weird :)

I would try something like this:

1, Get an instance of your kernel. Check `public/index.php` about how to do that.

`$kernel = new Kernel($env, $debug);`

2, Create a request manually

`$request = new Request([], [], ['_controller' => MyController::class . '::myAction']);`

3, Handle the request

`$kernel->handle($request);`

4, Send the response, and terminate the kernel (like in index.php)

Tested it with a custom front controller, see https://gist.github.com/Padam87/27a7d0825816fa358678bce7a640dd47

If you only need the response body, then use `$response->getContent()`.

Comment: This looks good! Didn't know that I could add _controller directly to the Request; also, RouterListener will abort if _controller is already set; nice. I guess Request::createFromGlobals() will work, too. $response->sendContent() should be the last piece to the puzzle. Will check tomorrow.

Comment: Request forwarding (in a controller) works the same way BTW :)